# Undefined persian text when append Html by JavaScript

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using Web socket in my chat project, when send message real time by appending HTML like below code from javascript to view, Persian text like '?' show!

Please help me ...

```
$('#messages').append('<Li class="self"><div class="message"><div class="content" lang="fa">' + Message_Text + '</div></div></Li >');
```

Comment: it seems encoding issue check the var Message_Text  value from where it is assign value

Comment: Message_Text get from web socket manager java file like argument , i do not know how to change value in web socket manager java file...